# Override datatables options

Tags: jquery, datatables

I use datatables everywhere on my website and each table has its own properties

Example :
index.php

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fileTable').dataTable({
      "aaSorting": [],
      "columnDefs": [{"orderable": false, "targets": 5}],
    });
  });
```

archives.php

```
$('#fileTable').dataTable({
    "columnDefs": [
        {"orderable": false, "targets": 3}
    ]
});
```

I want to change the texts of all tables without change **jquery.dataTables.min.js**

So I put that in the footer :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fileTable').dataTable({
      language: {
        search: "",
        searchPlaceholder: "Search...",
        sLengthMenu:"_MENU_",
        sInfo:"_TOTAL_ elements"
         }
    });
  });
```

But I have this error :
**DataTables warning: table id=fileTable - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3**

How I can do this properly (without destroy)

Thank you

Comment: There is no recommended way of updating settings after initialisation ([source](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/4010/set-options-programmatically-after-table-initialization)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is place the language settings in a separate object which you then `$.extend()` for each instance to add their own custom settings, something like this:

```
var langSettings = {
  language: {
    search: "",
    searchPlaceholder: "Search...",
    sLengthMenu: "_MENU_",
    sInfo: "_TOTAL_ elements"
  }
}

// for index.php:
$('#fileTable').dataTable($.extend(langSettings, {
  "aaSorting": [],
  "columnDefs": [{
    "orderable": false, 
    "targets": 5
  }]
}));

// for archives.php:
$('#fileTable').dataTable($.extend(langSettings, {
  "columnDefs": [{
    "orderable": false, 
    "targets": 3
  }]
}));
```

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work, I added "var langSettings" on header and added "$('#fileTable').dataTable($.extend(langSettings.." But there is no change

Comment: Apologies - I missed the outer `language` object. Try my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

As the error states you can't `reinitialise DataTables` .But as long as you initialize your table in each page just add your preferred text.